# Error downloading pdf generated by JasperReports via servlet post

Tags: java, servlets, jasper-reports, pdf-generation

I generate the report and the user can receive but only one piece, in the normal format of the same report it comes out complete.

Follow the code, if you can help thank you, I've hit the head with it a few days ago, it sure is my mistake but I could not see it.

Follow the code:

```
public class DownloadNovadata extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private UsuariosNovadata usuariosNovadata;

    private String dni;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Entrei no doGet");
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        dni = req.getParameter("dni");

        HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        UsuarioNovadata ugc = usuariosNovadata.porDni(dni);
        parametros.put("p_Novadata_id", ugc.getNovadata().getId());
        String nomeRelatorio = "NovadataSQL";

        HashMap paramRel = new HashMap();
        String imagemLogo = "/Users/images/iofe.jpg";
        paramRel.put("imagemLogo", imagemLogo);
        paramRel.put("REPORT_LOCALE", new Locale("pt", "BR"));
        JasperPrint print = null;
        try {
            Connection con = null;
            String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
            String user = "userName";
            String senha = "password";
            String url = "jdbc:postgresql://site:5432/dbname";
            try {
                Class.forName(driver);
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, senha);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                System.err.print(ex.getMessage());
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.print(e.getMessage());
            }
            print = JasperFillManager
                    .fillReport("/relatorios/" + nomeRelatorio + ".jasper", paramRel, con);
            JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);
            ServletOutputStream out = res.getOutputStream();
            res.reset();
            res.setContentType("application/pdf");
            res.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=" + dni + ".pdf");
            res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            res.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
              baos.writeTo(out);
              out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static long getSerialversionuid() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check generated report? Is it ok? `in the normal format of the same report it comes out complete` - What do you mean? The problem is not clear

Comment: Note that `out.flush()` should probably be `out.close()`. Consider using try-with-resources instead, which won't solve the problem, but will avoid running out of file descriptors over time.